# Manipulate Windows Services with .NET / C# like Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-services

What library in .NET would allow you to stop, uninstall, unregister, install, and start Windows Services from .NET? I am using .NET 4/4.5.

What does get-service from Powershell call behind the scenes? How can I get access to the same objects/API from .NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) to do most of that (Start, Stop, Pause and so forth). It requires that you add the `ServiceProcess.dll`. It can't do everything though, so I use command prompt calls like `sc create`

Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21187278/885318

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate existing services with the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)-class. To create an service, you need to use native methods using P/Invoke. See [CreateService (advapi32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.CreateService) and [DeleteService (advapi32):](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.DeleteService)

That's how the PowerShell cmdlets does it.

You can find examples for using `CreateService` and `DeleteService` in C# [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sachin.nigam/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically11262005061332AM/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically.aspx).